# Firestore query on maps

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In a firestore query, how do I check whether an element is the key in a map or not?

For example, I have this document:

[image]

I want to check if user's UID matches one of the UIDs in the "authors" map data structure. All the answers that I've seen so far so "where" but I don't think that's allowed syntax for Firestore queries anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't query on keys like that (at least not that I know of).

I instead recommend adding a field `authorUids` that is an array of the UIDs of the authors. With that array, you can then use the `array-contains` operators:

```
collectionRef.where('authorUids', 'array'contains', 'ppGr1M8s...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't imagine how you got the impression that "where" is no longer valid (it is) - but in particular, "where" is a test on the *value* of a field (not it's existence), AND there is no test for "null" nor "not equal to".

BUT - speculating a tad here - you *might* be able to *fake* a non-null test in your case:

```
collectionRef.where('authors.'+ userUID + '.0', ">", U+0000)
```

(fix the notation as needed) meaning

setting fieldPath to the concatenated string author.ppGr1M8sQWVrrsna6MlcQqxzLA3.0 in your example

and the field Value to the Unicode character value 0 (i.e. the minimal lexical value possible for a string)

so ANY value of the string is greater than null, *if* it exists at all.

firestore documentation states that documents that do not contain the specified fieldpath will not be returned, but you still need a valid test on the value.  I **strongly** suspect this will result in creating a lot of inefficient indexes, and is highly NOT recommended.

An interesting exercise if this approach actually functions (I haven't tried it and don't intend to) - but really, find another structure - the convoluted explanation of the hack shows what a poor idea it really is.

The most important decisions, especially for a NoSQL database, are your structure/schema decisions - don't put too much effort into forcing yourself to work around bad schema/structure.